# Time difference in sql

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am having trouble getting time difference with function--

```
"SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2008-06-05','2008-08-05') "
```

above query returns error message saying

```
"Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'"
```

I have copied this code directly from w3schools.
(I want to get time between two parameters but that too is giving same error msg).

Comment: w3schools has nothing to do with w3c! It is one mans opinion and shouldn't be taken as fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use MySQL there are 2 arguments.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 23:59:59','2007-12-30');
```

if you use MSSQL there are 3

```
  SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'
, '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
```

MSSQL
http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms189794.aspx

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.

MySQL
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

DATEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.

Comment: So how can I subtract  two  "datetime" arguments, to get time difference in mysql.

Comment: Just do it - `SELECT FIRSTDATE - SECONDDATE FROM SOME_TABLE`  You should try it because the results will be informative - especially if you have a careful look at the result - its datatype and what the value might mean.

Comment: Also try this `SELECT SOMEDATE - 1 FROM SOME_TABLE` and `SELECT SOMEDATE - 0.5 FROM SOMETABLE`.  This should demonstrate to you how dates work in your database.

Comment: Thanks for refering me to link."select SUBTIME(ENDTIME,STARTTIME) from overtime" worked after changing datatype of the attributes.(Previously I was trying MSSQL functions.)

Answer (score 1):

[DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) takes two parameter. try to use it like

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2008-08-05')
```